# Copy release dll after build?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, nuget-package

I'm using nuget and after I build my release dll, I would like it to copy that dll to the package\lib folder that exists in the projects folder.

How is that done?

/Lasse

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under project properties, add the following post-build event:

```
copy "$(TargetPath)" "$(SolutionDir)package\lib"
```

Be sure to modify the path to your nuget package root. I assumed here that it was <Solution>\package

Comment: I get error "exited with code 1", I have removed read-only on the folders but still get error.

Comment: Probably because of whitespace in path, try `copy "$(TargetPath)" "$(SolutionDir)package\lib"`